# Change color line in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ado.net

How change color line in listview .
for example `if line == 4` then `line is red`

Comment: you are trying to change the background color of row 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to go through the whole list and colour each item conditionally, then you can use:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvw in myListView.Items)
{
    if (lvw.SubItems[x].ToString() == "True")
    {
        lvw.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Or if you always want to color the item at index 4:

```
myListView.Items[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: it gives me InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index error

Answer (score 1):

Might the answer be as simple as following?

```
listView1.Items[3].BackColor = Color.Red;
```